# Prevent date picker from scrolling with page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, antd

I am making a react app which has datepicker made up of [antd](https://ant.design/)

Simple **index.js** code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { DatePicker } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Select date-picker scroll bug.</h1>
    <div
      style={{ marginTop: "16px", width: 500, overflow: "scroll", height: 400 }}
    >
      <DatePicker />
      <div style={{ minHeight: 500 }}></div>
    </div>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**Working Example:**

[image: Edit antd reproduction template (forked)]

**To Reproduce**: If user clicks on the input, datepicker displayed but when we try to scroll down, the datepicker also get scrolled along with the page.

**Expected Result**: Datepicker should not get scrolled and it needs to be under the input box.

Any help would be highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in their FAQ: https://ant.design/docs/react/faq#How-do-I-prevent-Select-Dropdown-DatePicker-TimePicker-Popover-Popconfirm-scrolling-with-the-page?

1. Add `position: "relative"` to the parent element.
2. Add `getPopupContainer={trigger => trigger.parentElement}` to your `DatePicker`.

[image: Edit antd reproduction template (forked)]

Comment: The reason for this is that the popup is rendered as a modal, outside the parent component's DOM element. This fix sets the popup container to the parent of the trigger.